# Traer datos de una tabla cuya fecha sea menor a la menor de otra tabla

Tags: join, sql

Quiero hacer una consulta SQL para ver ciertas 'incongruencias' en una base de datos SQLServer.

Para simplificarlo un poco, pongamos que tengo una tabla `Movimiento_Paciente` que contiene un campo `pacienteId` y otro `fechaInicio`. En ésta tabla puede haber varios movimientos de un paciente, es decir, puede haber varios registros con `fechaInicio` diferentes para un mismo `pacienteId`.

Luego tengo otra tabla `Tratamiento`, que contiene los campos `nombre_tratamiento`, `pacienteId` y `fechaTratamiento`. Al igual que la tabla anterior, puede haber varios tratamientos con fechas diferentes para un mismo paciente.

Lo que quiero buscar son los pacientes cuya `fechaTratamiento` mínima sea inferior a la `fechaInicio` mínima de la tabla `Movimiento_Paciente`.

Lo que intenté fue algo así...

```
SELECT t1.pacienteId FROM Movimiento_Paciente t1 
INNER JOIN Tratamiento t2 ON t1.pacienteId = t2.pacienteId 
WHERE (SELECT MIN(fechaTratamiento) 
FROM Tratamiento 
GROUP BY pacienteId) < (SELECT MIN(fechaInicio) FROM Movimiento_Paciente 
GROUP BY pacienteId)
```

Esa consulta me da error porque obviamente esos `select` devuelven mas de un valor.

Estoy un poco trabado y no sé cómo hacerla. ¿Me podrían ayudar?

Muchas gracias, un saludo!!

Answer (score 2):

Dado un paciente, puedes obtener la mínima fecha de tratamiento de la siguiente forma:

```
select min(fechaTratamiento)
from Tratamiento T
where T.pacienteId = @pacienteId
```

Lo mismo para la mínima fecha de inicio...

Lo que resta entonces es comparar ambas fechas:

```
select pacienteId
from Movimiento_Paciente A
where (select min(fechaTratamiento)
       from Tratamiento T
       where T.pacienteId = A.pacienteId
      ) < (select min(fechaInicio) from
           Movimiento_Paciente B
           where A.pacienteId = B.pacienteId)
```

Esa consulta te da la lista de pacientes que buscas.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma es usar subconsultas para obtener la fecha mínima para las dos tablas y compararlas mediante un `JOIN`

```
SELECT  t1.pacienteId 
    FROM (SELECT    pacienteId,
            MIN(fechaInicio)                    AS 'fechaInicio'
            FROM Movimiento_Paciente
            GROUP BY pacienteId
        ) t1 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT  pacienteId,
                        MIN(fechaTratamiento)   AS 'fechaTratamiento'
            FROM Tratamiento
        ) t2 
        ON t1.pacienteId = t2.pacienteId 
    WHERE t2.fechaTratamiento < T1.fechaInicio
```

Esto te debería retornar todos los `pacienteId` de `Movimiento_Paciente` dónde la fecha mínima `fechaInicio` sea posterior a la fecha mínima `fechaTratamiento` de `Tratamiento`.

Answer (score 0):

si lo que quieres es que te devuelva un valor debes pasarle el id del paciente que tienes en la consulta y verificar que sean iguales, mas o menos tu codigo deberia quedar asi,

```
SELECT 
t1.pacienteId 
FROM Movimiento_Paciente t1 
INNER JOIN Tratamiento t2 ON t1.pacienteId = t2.pacienteId 
WHERE (SELECT MIN(fechaTratamiento) FROM Tratamiento where pacienteId = t1.pacienteId  GROUP BY pacienteId) < 
(SELECT MIN(fechaInicio) FROM Movimiento_Paciente where pacienteId = t1.pacienteId GROUP BY pacienteId)
```

Espero que te funcione.

Answer (score 0):

Propongo una alternativa a los selects anidados, que pueden resultar más lentos si las tablas tienen muchos registros, es utilizar having.

**Schema (PostgreSQL v10.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE Movimiento_Paciente (
  pacienteId INT,
  fechaInicio DATE
);
INSERT INTO Movimiento_Paciente (pacienteId, fechaInicio) VALUES (1,'2018-01-01');
INSERT INTO Movimiento_Paciente (pacienteId, fechaInicio) VALUES (1,'2018-02-01');
INSERT INTO Movimiento_Paciente (pacienteId, fechaInicio) VALUES (2,'2018-01-10');
INSERT INTO Movimiento_Paciente (pacienteId, fechaInicio) VALUES (2,'2018-02-01');

CREATE TABLE Tratamiento (
  pacienteId INT,
  fechaTratamiento DATE
);

INSERT INTO Tratamiento (pacienteId, fechaTratamiento) VALUES (1,'2018-01-10');
INSERT INTO Tratamiento (pacienteId, fechaTratamiento) VALUES (1,'2018-02-10');
INSERT INTO Tratamiento (pacienteId, fechaTratamiento) VALUES (2,'2018-01-01');
INSERT INTO Tratamiento (pacienteId, fechaTratamiento) VALUES (2,'2018-02-01');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT T.pacienteId , MIN(T.fechaTratamiento),
MIN(M.fechaInicio)

FROM Tratamiento T 
INNER JOIN Movimiento_Paciente M ON M.pacienteId = T.pacienteId
GROUP BY T.pacienteId
HAVING MIN(T.fechaTratamiento)<MIN(M.fechaInicio)
;

| pacienteid | min                      | min                      |
| ---------- | ------------------------ | ------------------------ |
| 2          | 2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z | 2018-01-10T00:00:00.000Z |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)